# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir objetos de otra clase?

Tags: php

tengo una clase llamada Fila, en el que voy añadiendo objetos a un array.
Mi clase Fila:

```
class Fila extends Celda{
    private $celdas = array();
    function __construct() {
    }
    function addCelda ($celda){
       array_push($this->celdas,$celda);
      }
    function pintarFilas(){
     for($i=0;$i<count($this->celdas);$i++){
      echo $this->celdas[$i];
     }
    }
}
```

El array es:

```
private $celdas = array();
```

Para añadir objetos a este array uso este método:

```
function addCelda ($celda){
       array_push($this->celdas,$celda);
      }
```

Y necesito imprimir este array, de tal manera que he usado esta forma de imprimirlo:

```
 function pintarFilas(){
     for($i=0;$i<count($this->celdas);$i++){
      echo $this->celdas[$i];
     }
```

La cosa es que echo no deja imprimir objetos, si no Strings, y el array contiene objetos de la clase Celda. Esta es mi clase celda:

```
class Celda {
    public $alin_vertical;
    public $alin_horizontal;
    public $color_fondo;
    public $contenido;

    function __construct($alin_vertical,$alin_horizontal,$color_fondo,$contenido) {
        $this->alin_vertical = $alin_vertical;
        $this->alin_horizontal = $alin_horizontal;
        $this->color_fondo = $color_fondo;
        $this->contenido = $contenido;
    }

    function pinta_celda() {
        echo "<td align='$this->alin_horizontal'
        valign='$this->alin_vertical'
        bgcolor='$this->color_fondo'>   
        $this->contenido</td>";
    }
}
```

Necesito que en cada interación, en el método pintarFilas se pueda llamar al método pinta_celda de la clase Celda.

Comment: *Necesito que en cada interación, en el método pintarFilas se pueda llamar al método pinta_celda de la clase Celda.* -> Efectivamente... y sabiendo lo que necesitas, por qué no lo haces en vez de poner un simple `echo $this->celdas[$i];`???  Cambia el echo por un `$this->celdas[$i]->pinta_celda()`  a ver qué pasa...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me estaba rompiendo la cabeza! A veces las cosas más sencillas nos vuelven loco y más con la presión de una entrega! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Asuminiento que tienes una estructura como la siguiente :

```
$array = [ 
    0 =>[
        "nombre"=>"Jose",
        "apellido"=>"Aleman"
    ],
    1 =>[
        "nombre"=>"Juan",
        "apellido"=>"Aleman"
    ]
];
```

Tu funcion `pintarFilas` deberia ser la siguiente

```
function pintarFilas(){
    foreach ($this->celdas as $key => $objeto) {
        foreach ($objeto as $clave => $valor) {
            echo  "$clave : $valor <br>";
        }
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

Nota : suelo utilizar ciclos `Foreach` pero puede ser facilmente adaptada a ciclos `for`

Comment: Estás asumiendo que lo que intenta hacer es imprimir en pantalla simplemente los valores, cuando en realidad el método al que pretende llamar devuelve un elemento `TD` de html. Tu respuesta no funcionaría simplemente porque por ejemplo la clave `color_fondo` debe ser pintada como `bgcolor`, `vertical_align` debe ser `valign`, etc... Ergo, esta respuesta, si bien sirve para recorrer un array de objetos complejos e imprimirlos, no sirve como respuesta a esta pregunta específica puesto que ***eso no es lo que busca el autor***.

Comment: @Benito-B  bueno no nos pongamos exquisitos.

Comment: Define *"ponerse exquisito"*, por favor. Según tú la definición de ponerse exquisito es "Querer que una respuesta haga referencia a la pregunta planteada", según mi experiencia en SO... eso es lo que indican las reglas, no exquisitez personal. Si me pusiese exquisito te habría dicho que tu pregunta tiene muy mala relación explicación/código. Me gustan las cosas muy bien detalladas cuando se trata con usuarios que están aprendiendo a programar. Pero nop, solo mencioné que tu respuesta en su estado actual ***NO RESPONDE A LA PREGUNTA***.